# Find a ring homomorphism $ϕ$ such that $ϕ(1_R)$ is not same $1_S$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find a ring homomorphism $ϕ$ such that $ϕ(1_R)$ is not same $1_S$, even if R$ and S$ are rings with multiplicative identities 1_R and 1_S,respectively.

I found $ϕ(1_R)=1_S.$

$ϕ $: surjective homomorphism, then $1_S=ϕ(r)$ for some $r∈R$.

$ϕ(1_R)=ϕ(1_R)*1_S=ϕ(1_R)ϕ(r)=ϕ(1_R*r)=ϕ(r)=1_S.$

But what is $ϕ(1_R)$ is not same $1_S$?

Comment: Are you given $R$ and $S$?   Or are you looking for an example of $R$, $S$, and $\phi$ with this property?  And why do you expect that $\operatorname{im}\phi$ contains $1_S$?  There is no assumption that $\phi$ is surjective, right?  Maybe, just post the whole problem that you are given.

Answer (score 2):

You're right that a *surjective* multiplicative map $\phi: R \to S$ must send $1_R$ to $1_S$.

In general, a multiplicative map $\phi: R \to S$ must send $1_R$ to an idempotent of $S$ because $\phi(1_R)^2=\phi(1_R^2)=\phi(1_R)$.

A simple example of a ring that has non-trivial idempotents is a product ring $S=A \times B$. Then $(1_A,0)$ and $(0,1_B)$ are non-trivial idempotents of $S$.

So, the map $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ given by $x\mapsto (x,0)$ gives you an example.