# How to prove that $Ф(1) = 1'$ if $R'$ is an integral domain?

Tags: ring-theory, integral-domain, ring-homomorphism

[image]Since $R'$ is an integral domain , $Ф(b) = Ф(b.1) = Ф(b).Ф(1) = Ф(1).Ф(b)$ .But i can prove this only for those $r'∈R'$ for which there $∃r∈R$ such that $Ф(r)=r'$.

Comment: I would say that you'd have to add a bit more context to the question. $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism $\phi:R\to R'$ I suppose? I guess you're saying that you can only prove $\phi(1)=1_{\phi(R)}$, i.e. the identity in the subgroup $\phi(R)\subset R'$, which I believe is the case yes.

Comment: Corr.: subgroup->subring.

Comment: @Christopher.L added the pic

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2956429/find-a-ring-homomorphism-ϕ-such-that-ϕ1-r-is-not-same-1-s

Comment: That is right, you can show this when $R'$ is an integral domain, silly of me. Well, as a hint I can start by saying, suppose $\phi(1)\not= 1'$, then can you say that $\phi(1)$ is a zero divisor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prove it, because there's a small mistake: we can't rule out the possibility that $\phi$ is the map that sends everything to $0$.

So if $R'$ is an integral domain, then we can show that either $\phi(1)=0$ or $\phi(1)$ is an identity of $R'$ as follows:
$\phi(1)=\phi(1^2)=\phi(1)^2$, so if we assume that $\phi(1) \neq 0$, then we get for every $r' \in R'$, $\phi(1)(r'-\phi(1)r')=0$, so $r'=\phi(1)r'$, thus $\phi(1)$ is an (or the) identity element in $R'$.

Comment: when you write $\phi(1)(1-\phi(1))=0$   Then you are assuming that $R'$ has identity element. it is also possible that $R'$ does  not have identity element  .So while moving from   $\phi(1)=\phi(1^2)=\phi(1)^2$   to $\phi(1)(1-\phi(1))=0$ we should assume that $R'$ has identity element .

Comment: @Amit you're right, I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* $\phi(1)$ is idempotent.